# How to fix Grails 2.4.4 "Error: Interactive mode exited with error" on Linux (Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS)

Tags: grails

I use Grails 2.4.4 to work on a project and recently I have not been able to use the interactive mode. I am still able to run `grails` commands outside of the interactive mode. Below is what I see when I run `grails --stacktrace`

Is there a way to fix this error so that I can use interactive mode again?

I have tried reinstalling Java, reinstalling Grails, updating to the latest Java 7 version, and restarting computer.

Grails interactive mode console error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpkxa.png